# Windows 10 ftp client access works on 2.4ghz band but not on 5ghz band?

Tags: router, connection-sharing

I have a dual band archer C7 router.  I am able to access the ftp server through FileZilla client running on windows 10 on the 2.4ghz band, the 5ghz band won't connect(it times out).  I disabled the firewall, checked file sharing and network discovery(both on), the firewall is disabled.  Looked online not much on this topic, I can't figure it out.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Where is the FTP server? On your router/LAN? Or on the Internet?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the case to be former and you mis-joined the guest 5GHz SSID, if any.

Comment: The ftp server is on a android phone.  I tried multiple times, the SSID on both devices is the same (on same network).  The 2.4ghz will connect and the 5ghz wont.

Comment: Neither 'file sharing' (SMB) nor 'network discovery' (WS-Disc + NetBIOS) have anything to do with FTP connections to an IP address or a domain name. Where is the server hosted – is it local to the LAN, or somewhere over the Internet? What IP addresses & gateways does your Windows 10 computer receive over the 2.4GHz band and over the 5GHz band?

Comment: Right.  I mentioned that in the post because thats the first thing one might suggest to try.  So the server is hosted on a andriod phone on a local network.  The ip address and gateway stay constant over the network at 192.168.2.110 and 192.168.2.1 over both bands.